# UILabel center align issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a strange issue with UILabel.

I have a countdown module in my app that displays the days/hours/minutes/secs to a particular date.

All of the values are displayed in UILabels with center alignment.

The issue is when we go from 2 digits to 1 digit, the text is no longer center aligned.

I put the following code in the method that is called each second to try and resolve this, but no luck:

```
 secondLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
 secondLabel.baselineAdjustment =  UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters;
 secondLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d", components.second];
```

Do I have redraw the label each time I put the number in there?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: is your label changing sizes when you change the text in it, or is it always the same size?

Comment: It is always the same size. It is placed in interface builder, when I put one digit in the label in IB, it looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@"%02i"` instead `@"%2d"` in the `stringWithFormat:` NSString selector...

Comment: That was the issue. Changing %2d to %d (or %i) fixes the issue. Thanks.